# how to email,share and print pdf?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, share

I'm developing an iOS application.I'm newbie in files manipulation in iOS. I'd like to email, share and print each pdf files. Those pdf files were bundled.

In my View Controller, I created 3 buttons:

1. Email
2. iBooks
3. Print

What should I do to attain those actions?

Comment: Use SLComposeViewController for [email support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: [You question is way too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Did you try googling for tutorials/examples before asking here? If so, what did you try?

Comment: I used UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpgul to you for E-mail:

First of all, import `MessageUI.framework` in your application.

And your device or simulator must be configured with one of your e-mail accounts.

Then, your e-mail button click event will look something like this:

```
-(void)ClickOnEmailUs
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker;
    picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if(picker)
    {
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [picker setToRecipients:receipientsArrayOfStrings];
            [picker setSubject:@"Your Subject"];
            [picker setMessageBody:@"E-Mail Body" isHTML:YES];
            [picker addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"file.pdf"];  // for adding attachment to the mail
            [self.navigationController  presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *noEmailAccountMsg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Please configure your email account." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [noEmailAccountMsg show];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add this line into the above code to right before presenting the MFMailComposer..

 [vc addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"file.pdf"];

It would help for the attachment